# Taxonomy view breaks when changing url

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I have a taxonomy view that outputs to the a page 
example.com/food/toast  that works correctly. It shows a list of nodes that have the term food within them.

When I try to change the path to meals/toast, the view breaks and I can not figure out why.

Any idea to help me??

Comment: Can you explain how you configured your view? Maube with some screenshots? What contextual filters did you use?

Comment: I copied the default taxonomy view. The contextual filters are  Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth) and Content: Has taxonomy term ID depth modifier.  The only other change I made was in the page path I changed it from taxonomy/term/%  to meals/term/%